# What are the marriage rituals of the Sea Folk?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

Towards the end of Book 7, *A Crown of Swords*,

> Lan and Nynaeve

get married among the Sea Folk. Later, the wife describes their marriage rituals as "embarrassing".

From later books we know that in public the wife has control over the husband, while in private it's the other way around, but not much else.

Do we ever find out what the marriage ritual actually consists of among the Sea Folk?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it involves rope, cooking oil, and salt... Juilin said something about it...

Comment: IIRC the one of higher rank is supposed to be "submissive" in the bedroom it is not a male female distinction but rather one of rank

Comment: @gowenfawr I see what you've done there :D

Answer (score 7):

This appears to be something of a [shrug-of-God trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShrugOfGod) moment where the author simply wanted fans to come up with [their own weird ideas](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoodleIncident). We can assume that Jordan *personally* had something odd in mind (consummating the wedding in public, for example) but there's no sign that he intends to share it with his readers.

> **Q:** *Tell us about those seafolk rituals during the wedding...*
>   **RJ:** *How old are you?*
>   **Q:** *Over the age of consent.*
>   **RJ:** *You're too young!*
>
> <sub><sup>http://linuxmafia.com/~pam/ACOS_signings.html</sup></sub>